# Generating Strings which can be encoded by a specific Charset in ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, character-encoding, scalacheck

In my ScalaTest test I need strings which can be encoded in US-ASCII. I tried checking if a string can be encoded in that charset after generating it with the default generator for Strings:

```
forAll { str: String =>
  StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newEncoder().canEncode(str) ==> {
    // my test code is here
  }
}
```

but I get an error:

> Gave up after only 8 passed tests. 501 tests were discarded.

Is there a simple way to generate strings which can be encoded in a particular charset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a generator that only produces valid characters

```
val usAsciiStringGen = Gen.containerOf[Array, Char](Gen.choose[Char](0,127)).map(_.mkString)
```

Then use it in the test:

```
val prop = forAll(usAsciiStringGen) { str: String =>
  ...
}
```

Note that the check isn't really necessary anymore since only US Ascii strings would be generated.

Comment: For-comprehension is not needed here. Upper limit should be 127, not 128.